# bash output to file

Tags: linux, bash, wine

i have the following statement

```
 for i in `cat i.txt`; do wine ~/run.exe $i.asc >> out.asc; done
```

but it keeps writing all the output to console not the file 'out.asc'. plz can you help me to redirect the output to file rather than screen. thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look into http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html. Maybe the sample 3.6 is the best for you.

Comment: You should also take the habit to quotes your variables. In this case `"$i"`. This matter because if your variable contains special charaters it will not be escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that wine is writing to stderr, so you need to redirect that:

```
for i in `cat i.txt`; do wine ~/run.exe $i.asc 2>> out.asc; done
```

Notice the **2** in the `2>>` operator, this means stderr.

Comment: This will not output the stdout to out.asc. Only the stderr will be redirected.

Comment: so, `>> out.asc 2>&1` would redirect both

Answer (score 4):

try with redirecting stderr (2) to stdout (1)

```
for i in `cat i.txt`; do wine ~/run.exe $i.asc >> out.asc 2>&1; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have both a standard output and erro outputs. Use `>>` and `2>>` to redirect both output stream to your file.

```
for i in `cat i.txt`; do wine ~/run.exe $i.asc >> out.asc 2>> out.asc; done
```

You could optionally redirect sources to different files:

```
for i in `cat i.txt`; do wine ~/run.exe $i.asc >> out.asc 2>> err.asc; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Other have answered your actual question, I'd like to show a better idiom to read the lines of a file.

Instead of

```
for i in `cat i.txt`; do
  : do something with $i
done
```

Try

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  : do something with "$i"
done < i.txt
```